# How do I force the cursor to the end of a NSTextField?

Tags: cocoa

I am NSOpenPanel to select a file or folder from a user's machine.  But when the user clicks "open" the cursor is at the beginning of the path that shows up in the text field.  This is a problem because until you click in the textfield and arrow right, you won't see that the entire path is listed.  For example if the path is:

```
/Users/jeremysmith/code/testfolder/testfolder2
```

It may only show:

```
/Users/jeremysmith/code/
```

since the cursor is at the beginning and the text field's width only goes to "code".

Answer (score 27):

I got this working on textfields by doing:

```
[[self.inputFileTextField currentEditor] moveToEndOfLine:nil];
```

Comment: If the text field is initially not Editable I had to send
`[self.inputFileTextField selectText:self]` in order to make the above code work.

Comment: @RotsiserMho I have a textfield thats not editable and I tried your suggestion but it still won't work. Did you call selectText before or after you call moveToEndOfLine?

Answer (score 6):

Here's my Swift solution:

```
self.fileTextField.currentEditor()?.moveToEndOfDocument(nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, since it's 2015:

```
self.textField.moveToEndOfDocument(nil)
```

Comment: Not sure how this is possible, but I get an invalid selector crash when calling moveToEndOfDocument: on my NSTextField subclass, even though that method is an extension on NSResponder which an NSTextField is...

Comment: @BenBaron are you positive you have what you think you have at runtime?

Comment: Yeah the exception confirmed the object was my custom subclass of NSTextField, so it should have worked. I ended up using simon.d's answer on the same text field and it worked fine, so it was definitely a text field as it was able to get the field editor.

Comment: Thanks @BenBaron. That's odd, but subclassing some of these UIKit classes produces weird results. I do it a lot, though...

Comment: `moveToBeginningOfDocument` and `moveToBeginningOfLine` is not implemented on text fields (but it is on text views, and this in the field editor)

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas spring to mind. First, you could use [`-[NSTextView setSelectedRange:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000373-BBCCGHBB):

```
NSTextView * fieldEditor = [thePanel fieldEditor:NO forObject:theTextField];

NSUInteger text_len = [[fieldEditor string] length];

[fieldEditor setSelectedRange:(NSRange){text_len, 0}];
```

Or you could use one of the `NSResponder` action methods on the text field, like [`moveDown:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000015-moveDown_), [`moveToEndOfLine:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000015-moveToEndOfLine_), [`moveToEndOfParagraph:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000015-moveToEndOfParagraph_), &c. Faking a "Page Down" or "Down Arrow" keypress with `[theTextField keyDown:...]` might also work.