# How to move caret (cursor) to the end of the line in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is probably an easy task, but Im new to cocoa, and haven't found the solution yet.

The algorithm I wrote accepts and validates user's input. It accepts only numbers and then takes the input to the acceptable form, which is nn:nn:nn where nn is a two digit number.

The way the algorithm works is following:

1. accept the digit
2. check if we need to insert :
3. add to final string

So what happens is that after user typed in 123 in a text field it looks like: 12:|3 (where | is the cursor position)

As you can understand if user types 12345 for example the input will look like: 12:45:|3 which is wrong.

I see the fix for this as just a simple move of the cursor to the end of the line after I do the : insertion. But I can't find the way to do it so far. :(

If anyone can help me to fix this bug, I would really appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try these :

```
[[self.inputFileTextField currentEditor] moveToEndOfLine:nil];
```

If you have textView then,

```
moveToEndOfParagraph:
```

or

```
NSTextView * textView = [thePanel textView forObject:theTextField];

NSUInteger text_len = [[textView string] length];

[textView setSelectedRange:(NSRange){text_len, 0}];
```

Comment: I have already read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113371/how-do-i-force-the-cursor-to-the-end-of-a-nstextfield it doesn't work for my case

Comment: sorry...it's not possible...lots of privacy issues ;)